# What do the state and coordinator columns in AKHQ mean?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am working with AKHQ and am trying to figure out what the state and coordinator columns mean in the consumer group tab. The documentation doesn't cover it. I can't find a tag for AKQH so assuming kafka is the proper one.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late question but I don't know people ask question about akhq on stackoverflow.

The state of AKHQ is state from Kafka that is documentation [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-coordinator-group-GroupMetadata.html)

Most important :

- `Empty`: No consumer are connected
- `PreparingRebalance`: consumers are just joining and wait for a rebalance
- `CompletingRebalance`: consumers rebalanced is done and wait to be completed
- `Stable`: The group have consumer and is active

For the `Dead` I have never seen by myself